# Angular project keeps refreshing

Tags: angular

I have spring boot as backend, and angular as front end,
when I open the application localhost:4200, the page keeps refreshing after couple of seconds).

althoug It wasn't before, seems there is a configuration issue because it was working just fine before.

what should I check ?

Comment: If your Angular application uses client-side routing (i.e., Angular Router), incorrect route configurations can cause the application to refresh. Ensure your route configurations are correct, and that you're not accidentally triggering a route change that causes a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on localhost I assume you are actively working on the application. Could this be caused by hot reload? Angular will automatically update your page if the code changed.

Comment: No, I am not doing any code change, just using the application.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have same case when any change made to code then it randomly reload more than once. In my case problem occur because of `service worker` [PWA] functionality. Just try to remove PWA related package & comment the code might be solve the issue.
Clear the cache of browser to get latest effect when you are run again after removing Service worker package.[In my case this is happening]